# Are there tutorials or videos about how to use Instruments to find memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, instruments

I have found some big memory leaks with instruments but have no idea how to figure out where in my code they are. Need some tuts on how to go about that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do this: [IPHONE: Analyzing leaks with instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634067/iphone-analyzing-leaks-with-instruments/1639237#1639237).

It's not obvious from the Instruments' documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question, but here is a good tutorial.

http://www.mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

Also, here's a link to the original question:

[How do you detect memory leaks on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494327/how-do-you-detect-memory-leaks-on-iphone)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you linked to. He is asking a specific question about finding the location of the leaking code in the Instruments interface. The linked question is a general, "How do I find leaks" query.